# Gridview1 Edit event to Common Routine () to Gridview1 onRowEdit

Tags: asp.net

In aspx web site Whenever Gridview Edit event is raises in my project .  it first call one common routine for validate edit Authorization and then it continue its event its possible.. ??

like

Gridview1 Edit event - > Common Routine () ->Gridview1 onRowEdit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `PreInit` method. So you can add on your code behind like bellow:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do something...
}
```

Also look at ASP.net Page life Cycle at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

### Update

If you want that `PreInit` execute on all your page. Simply, just create new common class inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and all your pages inherit from that common class. look at code sample:

```
//file name: Common.cs
public class Common : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //do something...
    }
}

//file name: YourPage.aspx.cs
public class YourPage : Common {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,  what i need  is  in my project i have more that 100 pages so i dont want to touch and change every thing.  simple one Add-on will take care of operation is needed. its possible